# Upload file along with text in Create view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My first .Net/MVC project, I generated a view that allows me to list, edit, and create items in a database, and I would like to add a file upload control to the Create page, to just upload one file.

I understand that within [HttpPost] I need "public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)" but my current [HttpPost] is like this: "public ActionResult Create(lm_pics lm_pics)".

Comment: Could you show how your current view look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have 2 file inputs? Why do you have 2 forms? Isn't the first form sufficient (assuming of course you add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to it as you cannot upload files without it)?:

```
@model PictureUploader_MVC.Models.lm_pics
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Upload Picture</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>lmit_pics</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.brand)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.brand)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.brand)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.enabled)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.enabled)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.enabled)
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit">Create</button>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

and your controller action that will process the form submission:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(lm_pics lm_pics, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    ...    
}
```

Comment: I accidently posted code with two file inputs -- I was trying  lots of things.  In particular I was thrown off  by the above link that said to put the file input an another form.  I'll edit my post above to take out any misinformation.

Comment: Totally works!  I was not aware multiple parameters could be passed to Create.  Thanks.